# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of null

Tags: jquery

I have a an OS Commerce store running with a custom theme. In my console I see the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of null

The line in question is:

```
<li><span class="tdbLink"><a id="tdb1" href="/index.php">Home</a></span><script type="text/javascript">$("#tdb1").button().addClass("ui-priority-secondary").parent().removeClass("tdbLink");</script></li>
```

The error doesn't make much sense since I believe the button() method will force the selected element to behave like a button. I can see that the anchor link has the id which the selector uses, so why is it reporting the property as null?

I thought this might be related to how the js libraries are included. They are referenced in the head section of the page as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/jquery.cookiebar.js"></script>
<script type="text/plain" class="cc-onconsent-inline-advertising" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/photoset-grid/jquery.photoset-grid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/colorbox/colorbox.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/osmart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/tabcontent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/css_browser_selector.js"></script>
```

It looks like there are two versions of jquery being used, this seems to be bad practise, what are the implications of this?

**UPDATE**

I have removed the duplicate js files includes so that I now have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/jquery.cookiebar.js"></script>
<script type="text/plain" class="cc-onconsent-inline-advertising" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/photoset-grid/jquery.photoset-grid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/osmart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/tabcontent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/css_browser_selector.js"></script>
```

I am still seeing the same error as before though.

Comment: One question, are you importing bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js?  I would bet you only need one of those.  I'm guessing.  Just noticed it.  Still reading.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` why are you including both? don't. You should only add the min version.

Comment: You include 2 versions of jQuery... That is BAD. That is why you have the problem

Comment: You are also including jQuery 1.11.2 with the 1.2.1 migration, then including 1.9.0 near the bottom which will cause problems.  I would suggest just bumping to 1.12.4...  //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js

Comment: Just wanted to add that the js which is included is how the purchased theme came. Looks like new libraries were added without considering the removal of any libraries no longer needed!

Comment: @fylzero I have removed the duplicate js file includes, I have updated my question but the same errors appear

Comment: @epascarello see my update to question

Comment: Your first line has a (presumably) invalid URL, which would prevent jquery from being included at all.  Can you update the src attribute to include https: and see if that helps?

Comment: @Daniel my console was not reporting a missing or invalid url, however I updated it to use a cdn v1.12.4 but it didn't change anything

Comment: It seems that if i change the $ to jQuery in this line the problem is resolved: $button .= '</span><script type="text/javascript">$("#tdb' . $button_counter . '").button('; to